# Random black screen crashes with audio loop

Tags: windows-7, audio, freeze, crash, hardware-failure

Been having this problem for a while actually (across multiple upgrades/replacements no less) but recently it's gotten a little bit worse. Sometimes my computer would randomly crash in the middle of something and play the last 0.5s of audio over and over then black screen. Only thing I can do after that is reset the computer. The weird part is, this happens extremely randomly and weirder still, rarely when I'm gaming or doing anything intensive.

It happens very rarely (like maybe once or twice a month) but it's been happening a bit more often lately. Usually this happens while streaming video online, sometimes while watching in VLC but for the first time it happened while I was playing an online game (Heroes of the Storm).

The only other weird problem I have is a probably malfunctioning wireless USB LAN card that sometimes freezes up. As in, out of nowhere, it would stop functioning for a while and anything using internet will freeze/hang (even chrome would become completely unresponsive). Sometimes it would also suddenly start getting massive spikes (random 100ms-500ms pings to the router while all other devices are perfectly fine) and I would have to unplug/replug it to bring it back to normal. Though since the audio loop crash happened once while I was watching on VLC, I'm not sure if this is the cause of the issue.

Here are my current PC specs, as well as parts that have recently been replaced (had other computer problems a few months back):

- Motherboard: Asus Sabertooth 990FXA
- Processor: AMD FX-8320E
- RAM: 2x G.Skill 8GB DDR3 1600Mhz (recently replaced, memtest no problems)
- HDD: 2TB Seagate (recently replaced), 1TB Seagate (with windows), 160GB WD
- GPU: AMD R9 390 (recently replaced, all drivers up to date)
- PSU: Coolermaster Silent Pro 700W

Given that, I'm not sure what the problem is anymore. Researching on this showed people with a vast number of problems, and since I've replaced numerous parts these past few months I have no idea what the problem is anymore... I'm just wondering if it could be the wireless LAN card or the PSU because everything else is pretty new

Comment: Please add a tag for your OS. Playing a sound loop while the rest of the system is not reponsive sounds like a driver problem (or a hardware problem which causes a driver to act up) with the sound driver playing the same buffer again and again. First thing I'd do is to make sure all drivers are updated to the most recent version.

Comment: All drivers have been updated but I'm still getting the same problem. It's been a month but no one has responded so I guess I'll just have to live with it.